# Get element ID of dynamically created div from on array using Java Script

Tags: javascript, html

I have created dynamic divs based on an array with ID.

```
NewArray = [parity1,parity2,parity3];
```

for that i got result like,

```
<div id="parity1"> </div>
<div id="parity2"> </div>
<div id="parity3"> </div>
```

Now i want to add some dynamic data inside each div, for that i have to fetch the ID of each div. but when i try to fetch the ID, it only shows the recent div id and stores all the data in the last div.

Loop for creating the dynamic divs

```
var tmpList = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < taskInfo[i].tasks.length; j++) {
        var flow = taskInfo[i].tasks[j].parity;
        console.log(flow);
        if (tmpList.indexOf(flow) < 0) { 
            tmpList.push(flow)
          }
    }

    for(var k=0; k < tmpList.length; k++) {
        var par = document.createElement("div");            
        par.setAttribute("id","Parity"+tmpList[k]);
        cont.appendChild(par);
      }
```

the array has some repeated values so the first loop remove those values whereas the second one creates the div

Comment: Add what you have done so far in the question

Comment: Can you add how you have created elements based on dynamic ids

Comment: There's no code fetching the IDs, please add the relevant part of your code to the question.

Comment: i have edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following simple loop helps me to resolve this issue. 
thanks for your answers, based on that i got this thought.

```
for(i=0; i < newArray.length; i++;)    
{
var x = document.getElementById("Parity"+newArray[i].parity);
x.appendChild(taskCont);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a specific `class` to all the divs which you want to pick and pick them using `document.querySelectorAll('.yourClass')`, this will give you list of all divs...

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, providing us with more code will help us get a better picture of your issues (as well as context).

In the meantime, below is a general solution.

```js
const newArray = ['parity1','parity2','parity3'];

//in this basic example, we use a hash map keyed by div id
const someData = {
  "parity1": 'foo',
  "parity2": 'bar',
  "parity3": 47
}

//get data for id
const getData = (id) => someData[id];

//manipulate div in some way
const populateElem = (div, data) => {
  div.innerText = data;
}

//iterate over each id in the array and populate
newArray.forEach(id => {
  const elem = document.getElementById(id);
  const data = getData(id);
  populateElem(elem, data);
});
```

```html
parity1: <div id="parity1"></div>
parity2: <div id="parity2"></div>
parity3: <div id="parity3"></div>
```

Some resources for you:

[Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

[HTMLElement.innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)

Also note that in JS, camelCase is usually used for variable names (hence the renaming of *NewArray* to *newArray*, whereas PascalCase is used for class declarations.